# Given a set of points, find a point minimize the distant between the set of points (linear)

Tags: geometry

I'm given a set of points that all of them are on a line, how to find the point that has the minimum distance to all other points? The point that we are looking for has to be on the line too. For example:
Given a set of points {1, 2, 3}
Then the point we are looking for is 2

Note that I checked J.H Butchart, Leo Moser's question, but I can't really understand it. if you can, please explain it to me. Thanks!

Comment: What you're looking for is the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Optimality_property) of the set of points.

Comment: I think I get it now...?

Comment: So you have a bunch of points on the line, i.e. a bunch of numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, etc. You want to find a number $y$ that is "closest to all of them." What does that mean? It means that the sum $|y - x_1| + |y - x_2| + ...$ of the distances between $y$ and each of your numbers is minimized. Imagine the "outermost" two numbers (1 and 3 in your example). If you place $y$ *anywhere* between them, the sum of distances between $y$ and those two will be constant and minimized. So anywhere between those two does the trick. continued...

Comment: Now consider the *next* two outermost numbers, i.e. 2 and 4 if your set is {1,2,3,4,5}. Anywhere in between them minimizes the total distance between $y$ and 2 and 4. Continue this argument all the inward and you are left with the median as defined in the wiki link above. If there are an even number of numbers, anywhere between the middle two numbers works. If there are an odd number of numbers, the middle number is the solution.

Comment: Ok! I think I get it now! Thanks a lot!